# Reference class functions in the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

This extension of the Math object works well:

```
var MathClassExtensions = {
    randomNumber: function(minimum, maximum){
        return Math.round( Math.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum );
    } 
};
$.extend(Math, MathClassExtensions);

Math.randomNumber(4,9) //=> 4,5,5,3,1,8,9
```

However, I'm just concerned by `Math.round( Math.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum );` We appear to be calling the Math object from within the Math object...

Is this really a big deal? I still think it would feel nicer if I could do something like this:

```
self.round( self.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum );
```

However, the above is pseudo code and doesn't work. How can I get it to work?

*Update*

Or, is the randomNumber attribute evaluated when it's part of the MathClassExtensions object, and so using self or an equivalent would be completely meaningless?

Comment: @DavidThomas Oops. Fixed. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can do this by using `this`:

```
var MathClassExtensions = {
    randomNumber: function(minimum, maximum){
        return this.round( this.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum );
    }
};
```

I would recommend against it.  The problem is that you've now bound what should be a reusable function to a single execution context.  It's easier to demonstrate the issues with a function of a single parameter, although it still exists in your version:

```
var MathClassExtensions = {
    rand1: function(maximum){
        return Math.round(Math.random() * maximum);
    },
    rand2: function(maximum){
        return this.round(this.random() * maximum);
    }
};

$.extend(Math, MathClassExtensions);

Math.rand1(100); //=> 64 (for example)
Math.rand2(1000); //=> 357 (for example)
```

So far, so good.  But what if we use `Math.rand1`/`Math.rand2` as a plain function rather than a static method of `Math`?

```
[10, 50, 200].map(Math.rand1); //=> [10, 44, 157] (for example)
[10, 50, 200].map(Math.rand2); //=> TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The trouble is that run this way the function `Math.rand2` is just a function, not tied to the `Math` object.  When it's called, `this` is the current context (possibly the global [window?] context) and doesn't have `round` or `random` functions on it.  But because `Math.rand1` doesn't use `this`, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, Javascript uses this and not self. Regardless, since the methods are static, I don't think there is a problem with this code